# Align some elements to baseline and others to bottom

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align two text elements with different font sizes to each others' baselines, but also align an image in the same line to their bottom. The problem I'm running into is that if only one of the two exists the overall alignment changes, which can cause a jarring effect when adding and removing elements with javascript.

I want to set it up so that the distance between the baseline of each element and its bottom is the same, so that it doesn't matter what kind of elements share the line with the image. Maybe there's some preprocessing I can do to calculate the baseline of the font based on line-height and font-size?

```
.line {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.line > span {
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.line > .b {
    font-size: 30px;
}
img {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/k48muk5e/).

Comment: have a look at display: table-cell and display : table-row. It's good for aligning thos kind of things. Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k48muk5e/2/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you just need to include: `vertical-align:bottom;` for your text as well (I'm doing it through the span tag here because that seems to be what you were trying to do.):

```
.line > span {
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: I want the baselines of the text to be aligned, as well.

Comment: @theazureshadow Are you sure? Different sized fonts with aligned baselines look, well, strange. Here are three different fiddles based on your code. Do any of them look like what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/k48muk5e/19/ (all bottoms match), http://jsfiddle.net/k48muk5e/20/ (text baselines match & image is at bottom of text), http://jsfiddle.net/k48muk5e/21/ (text baselines match & image matches bottom of parent text).

Comment: @theazureshadow I think the important thing to note is that the "baseline" is the bottom of the text without considering characters such as p and q that go below the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

If you add:

```
.line * { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

And remove the positions off the line > span

```
.line > span {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

This aligns all elements to the bottom, is that what you wanted?

Comment: No. Basically, I want the distance between the text's baseline and the bottom of the text element to be the same. If that were true, then I could align everything using `vertical-align: bottom`.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want. Maybe you could display them as inline block and use bottom margin for spacing? If the font size is variable specify this in 'em' and it will scale to font size.

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want to achieve, just move the line-height to .line:

```
div {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.line {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.line > span {
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.line > .b {
    font-size: 30px;
}
img {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 50px;
}
```